# neo4jclient get node labels

Tags: c#, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jclient

How do i get the labels of a node with Neo4jClient library

this is the code i ran and it returned the following error

> The return expression that you have provided uses methods other than
>   those defined by ICypherResultItem, Neo4jClient.Cypher.All or
>   Neo4jClient.Cypher.Return. The return expression needs to be something
>   that we can translate to Cypher, then send to the server to be
>   executed. You can't use chains of methods, LINQ-to-objects, or other
>   constructs like these. If you want to run client-side logic to reshape
>   your data in .NET, use a Select call after the query has been
>   executed, like .Return(…).Results.Select(r => …). This technique
>   maintains a clear separation between what is being executed
>   server-side (in Neo4j, via Cypher) versus client-side (back in .NET).

my code

```
public List<string> getLabels(MyEvent targetEvent)
{
    List<string> result = 
                        this.client.Cypher.Match("(newE:MyEvent)")
                            .Where((MyEvent newE) => newE.myid == targetEvent.myid)
                            .Return(newE=> newE.Labels().ToString())
                            .Results.ToList();
                    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs section "[Get all labels for a specific user](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples#get-all-labels-for-a-specific-user)" show this code:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User)")
    .Where((User user) => user.Id == 1234)
    .Return(user => user.Labels())
    .Results
```

Based in the error message in the question, I believe you only need to remove the `toString()` from the return, like this:

```
public List<string> getLabels(MyEvent targetEvent)
{
    List<string> result = this.client.Cypher.Match("(newE:MyEvent)")
        .Where((MyEvent newE) => newE.myid == targetEvent.myid)
        .Return( newE=> newE.Labels() )
        .Results.ToList();
        return result;
}
```